# Old hardware for encryption and backdoor free

Tags: encryption, hardware

I've read and seen articles on backdoors in the processors or at least the idea of that would render software based encryption worthless.

I do know that routers and lots of the newer devices all have backdoors in them which allowed china to crack several major businesses like google ect...

Would older hardware be more secure and offer better protection from decryption?

Answer (score 1):

I thought the word had spread that the NSA is pretty good too. Yes, chinese network gear is often seen by some as compromised by design. Though recent news reports suggest that gear from US-companies might get manipulated after it leaves the factory ([see here](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2014/05/12/greenwald-nsa-plants-backdoors-in-foreign-bound-routers/) or [here](http://www.wired.com/2013/09/nsa-router-hacking/)). Other manufactures are not above suspicion, too. Pick your poison!

**Picking old hardware is *not* a solution to this problem:**

1. Old stuff is *more likely to break* and gives your admin headache.
2. Often the *support is discontinued*. Therefore *no security updates* (or new backdoors as you like ;-) ) => There may be known remote exploits but no one feels responsible to fix it.
3. The *security features are out-dated*. For example: if you use an old access point and encrypt your wireless network using WEP *any* script kid breaks your encryption in 5 minutes or less.
4. Old network gear is *slow*. In particular if you use encryption that slows everything down.
5. It is unclear / unproven if or at which point some state may have started to plant backdoors. 3 years ago? 5, 7 or 10? (You seem to be especially afraid of chinese manufacturers: they deliver components and did so for years.)